# celerity submit form by pressing enter

Tags: jruby, celerity

I'm trying to use celerity to submit a form. This form has a generated link that is called when the user hits the enter button. How do I trigger this?

I know you can submit by finding the link / button and pressing .click(). But I want to submit by pressing enter.

I noticed that celerity form objects has a:

- (Object) submit
  Submits the form.

http://celerity.rubyforge.org/yard/Celerity/Form.html#submit-instance_method

but I cant seem to access it. Thanks in advance